# View uses the wrong template when cache is enabled

Tags: views, theming, 8

I'm using the latest version 8.2.4 of drupal core, which ships with view.

After enabling the internal cache system, some of my views get broken.

My view configuration is:

```
uuid: xxx
langcode: de
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - block.block.unternavigation_unternehmen
    - core.entity_view_mode.node.standort
    - field.storage.node.field_ansprechpartner
    - node.type.standort
    - system.menu.main
  content:
    - 'block_content:formulare:13194389-5c27-4811-aa91-478cd4d80d52'
  module:
    - node
    - user
id: standorte
label: Standorte
module: views
description: ''
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
core: 8.x
display:
  default:
    display_plugin: default
    id: default
    display_title: Master
    position: 0
    display_options:
      access:
        type: perm
        options:
          perm: 'access content'
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: false
          replica: false
          query_comment: ''
          query_tags: {  }
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Anwenden
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Zurücksetzen
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sortieren nach'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Aufsteigend
          sort_desc_label: Absteigend
      pager:
        type: some
        options:
          items_per_page: 20
          offset: 0
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: true
          uses_fields: false
      row:
        type: 'entity:node'
        options:
          relationship: none
          view_mode: default
      fields:
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          label: ''
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            make_link: false
            absolute: false
            trim: false
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            strip_tags: false
            html: false
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          plugin_id: field
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          exclude: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
      filters:
        status:
          value: '1'
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          value:
            standort: standort
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
      sorts:
        field_sortierung_value:
          id: field_sortierung_value
          table: node__field_sortierung
          field: field_sortierung_value
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          order: ASC
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          plugin_id: standard
      title: ''
      header: {  }
      footer:
        entity_block_content:
          id: entity_block_content
          table: views
          field: entity_block_content
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          empty: false
          tokenize: false
          target: 13194389-5c27-4811-aa91-478cd4d80d52
          view_mode: default
          bypass_access: false
          plugin_id: entity
      empty: {  }
      relationships: {  }
      arguments: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  footer_block:
    display_plugin: block
    id: footer_block
    display_title: Footer
    position: 5
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      display_description: ''
      footer: {  }
      defaults:
        footer: false
        filters: false
        filter_groups: false
      filters:
        status:
          value: '1'
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          id: status
          expose:
            operator: ''
          group: 1
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          value:
            standort: standort
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
        field_nicht_im_footer_value:
          id: field_nicht_im_footer_value
          table: node__field_nicht_im_footer
          field: field_nicht_im_footer_value
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          operator: '='
          value: '0'
          group: 1
          exposed: false
          expose:
            operator_id: ''
            label: ''
            description: ''
            use_operator: false
            operator: ''
            identifier: ''
            required: false
            remember: false
            multiple: false
            remember_roles:
              authenticated: authenticated
          is_grouped: false
          group_info:
            label: ''
            description: ''
            identifier: ''
            optional: true
            widget: select
            multiple: false
            remember: false
            default_group: All
            default_group_multiple: {  }
            group_items: {  }
          plugin_id: boolean
      filter_groups:
        operator: AND
        groups:
          1: AND
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  kontakt:
    display_plugin: page
    id: kontakt
    display_title: Kontakt
    position: 1
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: kontakt
      display_description: ''
      menu:
        type: normal
        title: Kontakt
        description: ''
        expanded: false
        parent: ''
        weight: -42
        context: '0'
        menu_name: main
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  standorte:
    display_plugin: page
    id: standorte
    display_title: Standorte
    position: 2
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      display_description: ''
      path: standorte
      footer: {  }
      defaults:
        footer: false
        sorts: false
      menu:
        type: normal
        title: Standorte
        description: ''
        expanded: false
        parent: 'menu_link_content:a1b2d8c6-75af-459e-937e-0d1c792ef9b4'
        weight: -48
        context: '0'
        menu_name: main
      sorts:
        created:
          id: created
          table: node_field_data
          field: created
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          order: ASC
          exposed: false
          expose:
            label: ''
          granularity: second
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: created
          plugin_id: date
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
  standorte_ansprechpartner:
    display_plugin: attachment
    id: standorte_ansprechpartner
    display_title: 'Standorte Ansprechpartner'
    position: 4
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      display_description: ''
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: true
          uses_fields: false
      defaults:
        style: false
        row: false
        fields: false
        footer: false
      row:
        type: 'entity:node'
        options:
          relationship: none
          view_mode: standort
      fields:
        field_ansprechpartner:
          id: field_ansprechpartner
          table: node__field_ansprechpartner
          field: field_ansprechpartner
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: null
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: entity_reference_entity_view
          settings:
            view_mode: standort
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
          plugin_id: field
      attachment_position: after
      displays:
        standorte: standorte
      footer: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_ansprechpartner'
  standorte_kurzbeschreibung:
    display_plugin: attachment
    id: standorte_kurzbeschreibung
    display_title: 'Standorte Kurzbeschreibung'
    position: 3
    display_options:
      display_extenders: {  }
      display_description: ''
      displays:
        standorte: standorte
      footer: {  }
      defaults:
        footer: false
        header: false
      header:
        entity_block:
          id: entity_block
          table: views
          field: entity_block
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          empty: false
          tokenize: true
          target: unternavigation_unternehmen
          view_mode: default
          bypass_access: true
          plugin_id: entity
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.permissions
      tags: {  }
```

The main structure is:

```
View:
  - Attachement before (standorte_kurzbeschreibung)
    node--view--standorte--standorte-kurzbeschreibung.html.twig
  - Page (standorte)
    node--view--standorte--standorte.html.twig
  - Attachment after (standorte_ansprechpartner)
    node--view--standorte--standorte-ansprechpartner.html.twig
```

When enabling cache, drupal uses same node template (both are set to display rendered node) for attachement before and page rows. The templates are using default suggestion hooks `node--view--view-id--display-id.html.twig`.

Also the configured block (footer_block) uses the same template when enabling cache.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is simple and possible a bit unfortunate for you.

Do not use node--view-* templates. They are broken.

See this core issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2728419). The problem is that fixing it would result in a performance regression for other sites that do not use that feature; as more cache variations have to be stored if the same node is displayed in multiple views.

Instead of that, use a unique view mode for your view that you can address as a template through that.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up working around this issue by creating a new content "display" mode called "Topper" (like a Teaser, but call yours whatever you want).

This allowed us to create a Twig template for that new Display using the `node--type--topper.html.twig` hint, instead of the `node--view--view-id--display-id.html.twig` hints.

Then we set the specific View to use that Display for the output (instead of, say, the Teaser), instead of themeing the View.